# List of all Android system resources dimen attributes

Tags: android

Since the most of the Android system resources attributes are not public, identifiers and its attributes have to be accessed via `getIdentifier` as follows (*example*):

```
public static int getStatusBarHeight(Context context) {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = context.getResources()
            .getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Where can I see the list of all the identifier that can be accessed by this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the `dimens` definitions in the source code of the Android Open Source Project on [GitHub](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml).

Note: the list may (and most likely will) be slightly different with each release - select the branch that corresponds to the Android version you are interested in.

If you are looking for the possible `defType` values when trying to access an identifier my guess is that those are platform-standard resource types, such as `bool`, `integer` etc. See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html).

[Here's a link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res) to Android's default resources from the current *master* branch.

Comment: GitHub link is the one I was looking for. Thank you.